# How to receive HTML form name in php after submiting HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have this code in HTML:

```
 <input type ="text" name="<?php echo $id_global;?>"</input>
```

Then after submitting the form, I am trying something like this, but it's not working:

```
$id_s = $_POST['$id_global'];
```

Comment: You can't do this because when you submit your form, the name will be something you don't know. It's $_POST something. You can do `print_r($_POST);` to find it

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the quotes,

try `$id_s=$_POST[$id_global];`

Comment: Then we will need more context around your code, because that is the only error we can see right now.

Comment: @zeeshansarfraz does this `$id_global` variable still contain a value after you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks `'`

```
$id_s=$_POST[$id_global];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with double quotes php will not consider variable between single quotes and try with this also :

```
<?php 
    $id_global = 'field_name';
?>
<form action="/Stackoverflow/index.php" name="testForm" method="POST">
    <input type ="text" name="<?php echo $id_global;?>" />
</form>

<?php 
if($_POST){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST[$id_global]);
}
?>
```

Edit the action as per your need

Comment: $id_global =$_GET['id'];    This is how i am storing value in $id_global; @Ashish Ranade